# Regex Number - Python

Tags: python, regex

> Need to select all the three line numbers

```
 420
 1-4094
 1,42,100-102,338,420,534,995,999,1050

Regex  = (\d+([-,]\d+)+)
```

> Regex which i am using is selecting only the last two lines, it need to
>   select even the first line. please help.

Comment: Change the last `+` to a `*`. Although your regex will also select e.g. `1-1-1` (just FYI - I have no idea whether or not this is what you want).

Comment: `+` means _at least on_. `*` means _some_

Comment: Thanks Bro, it works !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following regex should work (just change `+` to `*` on the last group):

```
(\d+([-,]\d+)*)
```